# What is an Entity in Apache OFBiz?

Tags: java, database-design, ofbiz

I am new to Apache OFBiz and I am trying to understand how it fits together on a high level. In the documentation, I frequently come across the terms "Entity" and "Entity Engine", but I don't see where "Entity" is defined. What is an Entity, and why it is such an important abstraction in Apache OFBiz?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/General+Entity+Overview

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Entity+Engine+Guide

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Entity+Engine+Configuration+Guide

The Apache OFBiz Entity Engine is even used by Atlassian Jira since its start and still.
They followed
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Running+a+standalone+entity+engine

Also this could help you to help yourself, notably videos:

https://www.google.com/search?q=ofbiz+entity+definition+of+an&ie=UTF-8

There are some more advanced here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Framework+Introduction+Videos+and+Diagrams

Globally you can find up to date help at:

https://nightlies.apache.org/ofbiz/stable/

Not forgetting the "Documentation" menu at  https://ofbiz.apache.org/

HTH

Comment: I find it incredibly strange that "Entity" is not defined in the manual or wiki. There is no sentence that says: "An Entity is a ....".